# AMSTeX table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

I'm using the docoumentclass `amsart`. Two things I don't like:

1. The table of contents (TOC) looks kind of poor, is there an easy way to change it? I like it from `article` more.
2. If I use `\section*{bla}` it still appears but without number in the TOC. How can I make a section that does not appear in the TOC?

Comment: For the second part see barbara beeton's answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8158/fix-for-amsart-cls-tableofcontents-bug-regarding-starred-sections)

Comment: I've marked your inline code with backticks `\``.

Comment: Thank you. Carsten: somehow I didn't find this answer via google...

Comment: I said something about the TOC in this [post at the LaTeX Community forums](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=10536), though honestly I don't know why you'd use amsart unless you were being forced to.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a problem with amsart? It is not the worst layout, is it?

Answer (score 2):

1. You could use a package for customizing the TOC, such as [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) or [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc).
2. is answered by Carsten. If you still need information, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

in the meanwhile I solved the problem (found it somewhere else

```
\makeatletter
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
  \else 
    \par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}% 
\begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
    \@ifempty{#4}{%
      \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
 }{%
   \@tempdima#4\relax
 }%
 \parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
 \rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
 #5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima #6\nobreak\relax
 \ifnum#1<0\hfill\else\dotfill\fi\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par
 \nobreak
 \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
```