# How to make \subsection not appear in the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs

How do I get a sub `\subsection{title}` I choose not not appear in the ToC and not interfere with the counting of the other `\subsection`'s?

Comment: Use the starred version `\subsection*{title}`.

Comment: be aware that, while `\subsection*` always suppresses the numbering, whether or not it also suppresses an entry from the toc depends on what document class you're using.  ams classes include starred (sub)sections in the toc, and other tactics are needed.  see the question [fix-for-amsart-cls-tableofcontents-bug-regarding-starred-sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8158/) for details.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the starred version of the sectioning command; this suppresses the numbering, the inclusion in the ToC and the updating of marks for possible header/footers:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want it to not suppress the numbering while hiding it from the TOC?

Comment: \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}