# Do not display empty subsection in beamer Warsaw theme

Tags: beamer

I have problem with empty subsections -- they are added even, when I set them using `\section*{}`.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}

\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 1}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 2}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 3}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 4}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection*{}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 1}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 2}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 3}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 4}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the navigation of section 1, there are 5 lines (last one has empty title), but in section 2, there are 4 lines.

How to force beamer not to add the last empty subsection? Empty section is not added to the navigation bar.

Section with 4 subsections and one empty subsection at the end:
[image: Section with 4 subsections and one empty subsection at the end]

Section with only 4 subsections:
[image: Section with only 4 subsections]

Comment: Well, you could comment it out, but I don't think that's what you mean. Are you trying to prohibit them from appearing in a table of contents somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "prohibit them from appearing..."? I know what I can do, but it is not so nice. I could comment out `\subsection*{}` compile two times, and put `\subsection*{}` again and compile one more time. Then it works as should.

Comment: out of curiosity: what is the purpose of the empty subsection?

Comment: That tells me what I need to know. I'm not a beamer guru by any stretch of the imagination, but what you want is to prohibit this section from appearing in the table of contents. In a normal LaTeX document, starring the command would work. I just tested your MWE and, after changing `warsaw` to `Warsaw`, it works as I think you want it to after two passes. Related: [How to make \subsection not appear in the ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58994/17423).

Comment: @samcarter, I have one slide on the end of section, that is not connected with previously described things, but is not wothy to mention it in the ToC or Navigation.
@SeanAllred, I haven't seen any changes when I changed `warsaw` to `Warsaw`. Additional problem with the change is that I use theme that is _somehow_ derived from the Warsaw theme (`\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{uoregon theme}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is similar to [samcarter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246880/5764) but with an interface:

- `\stopnavigation` turns off the [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) navigation;
- `\resumenavigation` turns it back on again.

The above interface redefined `\headcommand` in the `.nav` file to temporarily do nothing, rather than write *nothing* to the `.nav` at all. It may not be ideal, but it works in your case:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\makeatletter
\let\oldheadcommand\headcommand
\newcommand{\stopnavigation}{\addtocontents{nav}{\string\let\string\headcommand\string\@gobble}}
\newcommand{\resumenavigation}{\addtocontents{nav}{\string\let\string\headcommand\string\oldheadcommand}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 1}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 2}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 3}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 4}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\stopnavigation
\subsection*{}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\resumenavigation

\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 1}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 2}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 3}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 4}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is it enough to hide the subsection?

The following idea is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66633/36296 
(There you will also finde much additional explanation).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\let\origaddtocontents=\addtocontents
\def\dontaddtocontents#1#2{} % or \@gobbletwo if in \makeatletter ... \makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 1}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 2}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 3}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 4}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\let\addtocontents=\dontaddtocontents
\subsection{Invisible Section}
\begin{frame}this\end{frame}
\let\addtocontents=\origaddtocontents

\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 1}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 2}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 3}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 4}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]