# Appendices inside a section?

Tags: sectioning, appendices

How can create appendices "numbered" A, B, C within three different sections of a Lyx article document. In other words, I would like Appendix A to be at the the end of my first section, Appendix B to be at the end of my second Section, etc. 
I tried to use the Document ------> Start Appendix Here, but then I can't continue with the sections.

Comment: You should used an unnumbered section if you want that (`\section*{Appendix A}`). No more numerated stuff is expected after `\appendix`

Comment: Oh, and [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) :)

Comment: Usually, appendices are common `\chapter`s placed after the `\appendix` command in your input file, and you can't have a chapter inside a section. You have to respect the [hierarchy of sectioning commands](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_commands). Mario S. E.'s advice is sound, but perhaps you want to use `\subsection*{Appendix A}` if the "appendix" in question must be inside a section.

Comment: Silly question, not very Lyx versed... would that make them not appear in the ToC? I think I need them to appear...

Comment: You can use `\subsection*{Appendix A} \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Appendix A}`. The second command will add the unnumbered subsection in your ToC. You should get familiar with the sectioning commands. Follow the link in my ealier comment.

Comment: [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

Usually, appendices are common `\chapters` placed after the `\appendix` command in your input file, and you can't have a chapter inside a section; you have to respect the hierarchy of sectioning commands. Follow this [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_commands) to get more familiar with the sectioning commands.

In order to get headings such as "Appendix A", "Appendix B", etc. within a section, you could use the next level of depth of sectioning commands, i.e. subsections. Use the starred version to get an unnumbered subsection:

```
\subsection*{Appendix A}
```

However, in most classes--notable exceptions include `amsart`; see Ryan Reich's comment below--this will not produce any entry in your ToC, even if you have set the depth of your ToC to subsection level, using `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` (or higher).
You must add the entry for that unnumbered subsection "manually", using

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Appendix A}
```

In summary:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}     % dummy text
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Foo}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection*{Appendix A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Appendix A}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection*{Appendix B}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Appendix B}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. Let’s if it will be closed anyhow.

Comment: @Speravir Having appendices in a section seems outlandish but, who knows? Maybe my answer will help others...

Comment: Yes, I think the same.

Comment: Note that some classes *do* include unnumbered `\subsection*`'s, most notably (to me) the `amsart` class.  For that one you should *not* use `\addcontentsline`; to remove an unwanted one, see [barbara beeton's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8205/575).

Comment: @RyanReich Thanks I didn't know. I've never used such classes. I'll edit my answer.