# appendix package: making appendix subsections

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, appendices

The problem with the code below is, it treats the Safety section as its own independent section. So in the table of contents, I've got 'Appendices' and 'Safety' as separate sections. I want Safety to look like a subsection of the 'Appendices' section.

Also, how do I rename 'Appendices' to 'Appendix'? It just looks better. Is it through a `\renewcommand`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}    
\section{Introduction}
  this is my introduction
\appendix
\appendixpage
\section{Safety}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112860/21891) may be of interest. To change the appendix page name, use `\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix}` after loading the `appendix` package (see the [package documentation](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/pub/archive/macros/latex/contrib/appendix/appendix.pdf), page 3).

Comment: I think you should clarify your other problem, perhaps with an annotated screenshot of the output.

Comment: I fudged around the problem by not using \appendix

Answer (score 8):

My understanding of appendices in LaTeX is that you issue the `\appendix` command, and then carry on creating sections as before. You can have a `\section` called **Appendix**, and then within that, a `\subsection` called **Safety**.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
  this is my introduction
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Safety}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: May I ask if it is possible to change A. to SI. (as I have Supplementary Information instead of Appendix)? I wanted to use different sections for different parts of the SI and would like to ref them in the text like ...."this is shown in more detail in~\ref{mysisection}" and this should become "this is shown in more detail in SI.1". However, SI.1 should be "Supplementary Information 1" as a header (section). would that work?